# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in public players

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner

- I am new to jasmine and test cases
- I am trying to write test cases for my js code in fiddle.
- but I am facing aan error.
  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code below
- should I neot use players method??
- do I need to pass all the parameters for players

http://jsfiddle.net/2yw4o6z8/1/

```or-tag-here
public players(container: any, options: any, that: any,selectedoptions) {
    $(".displayInlineBlock").removeClass("SWIMMINGumentMobileDiplay");
    let SWIMMINGImageMobile = "SWIMMINGumentMobile";

    let extensionType = {
      ".pdf": "pdfMobile",
      ".ppt": "pptMobile",
      ".xls": "xlsMobile",
      ".xlsx": "xlsMobile",
      ".SWIMMING": "SWIMMINGumentMobile",
      ".SWIMMINGx": "SWIMMINGumentMobile",
      ".msg": "mailMobile"
    };
    let lastIndex = options.model.SWIMMINGumentName.lastIndexOf(".");

    SWIMMINGImageMobile = extensionType[options.model.SWIMMINGumentName.slice(lastIndex).toLowerCase()];

    if (typeof options.model.SWIMMINGumentMobile != "undefined" && options.model.SWIMMINGumentMobile != "") {
      SWIMMINGImageMobile = options.model.SWIMMINGumentMobile;
    }
    if (typeof SWIMMINGImageMobile == "undefined") {
      SWIMMINGImageMobile = "newDocMobile";
    }
    let kendotxtMenu = "";
    if (options.model.isElfDoc == true) {
      kendotxtMenu = "SWIMMINGumentMobileDiplay";
    }
    //"isElfDoc":true;

    let input = $("<span class='" + SWIMMINGImageMobile + " displayInlineBlock " + options.model.SWIMMINGumentlength + " " + kendotxtMenu + " ' ></span><ul class='fileTypeHolder' id='fileTypeMobiles' style='display: none;'><li class='fileTypeHolderTitle'>ELF Document Type</li><li><span class='SWIMMINGumentMobile displayInlineBlock' (click)='browseFileType(SWIMMING)'></span></li> <li><span class='xlsMobile displayInlineBlock' (click)='browseFileType('xls')'></span></li> <li><span class='pptMobile displayInlineBlock'(click)='browseFileType('ppt')'></span></li> <li><span class='pdfMobile displayInlineBlock' (click)='browseFileType('pdf')'></span></li><li><span class='newDocMobile displayInlineBlock' (click)='browseFileType('newSWIMMING')'></span></li><li><span class='mailMobile displayInlineBlock' (click)='browseFileType('mail')'></span></li><li class='fileTypeHolderCloseBtn'> <button id='CloseBtn' class='commonBtn'>Close</button></ul>");
    input.appendTo(container);
    // <button class='commonBtn' id='CloseBtn'>Close</button>
    this.selectedoptions = null;
    this.selectedoptions = options;
    $("#fileTypeMobiles").kendoContextMenu({
      target: ".SWIMMINGumentMobileDiplay",
      showOn: "click",
      open: function(e) {

        //  console.log($(this).index(this));
        // console.log($(this).index());
      },
      select: function(e) {

        //console.log(e.item.firstElementChild);
        //console.log(e.item.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.className);
        var ReturnClassName = e.item.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.className
        if (ReturnClassName == "commonBtn") {
          return false;
        }

        let firstClass = $("." + options.model.SWIMMINGumentlength).attr('class').split(" ")[0];
        var extensionType = {
          "pdfMobile": "pdf",
          "pptMobile": "ppt",
          "xlsMobile": "xls",
          "SWIMMINGumentMobile": "SWIMMING",
          "newDocMobile": "default",
          "mailMobile": "msg"
        };
        var classNames = "pdfMobile pptMobile xlsMobile SWIMMINGumentMobile mailMobile newDocMobile";

        var classes = $("." + options.model.SWIMMINGumentlength).attr('class').split(" ");
        $("#" + options.model.SWIMMINGumentlength).val("." + extensionType[ReturnClassName.split(" ")[0]]);
        options.model.SWIMMINGumentName = "";
        options.model.SWIMMINGumentName = "." + extensionType[ReturnClassName.split(" ")[0]];
        options.model.isElfDoc = false;
        for (var c = 0; c < classes.length; c++) {
          if (classNames.includes(classes[c])) {
            $("." + options.model.SWIMMINGumentlength).removeClass(classes[c]);

          }
        }
        options.model.SWIMMINGumentMobile = ReturnClassName.split(" ")[0];
        $("." + options.model.SWIMMINGumentlength).addClass(e.item.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.className);
        //$("."+options.model.SWIMMINGumentId).addClass("displayInlineBlock");
        $("." + options.model.SWIMMINGumentlength).addClass("SWIMMINGumentMobileDiplay");


        let data_source = that.gridkendo._dataSource.data();
        for (let d = 0; d < data_source.length; d++) {
          if (data_source[d].isElfDoc == true && data_source[d].elfDocID == "") {
            that.gridkendo.enableSaveDocument(false);
          }

        }

      }
    });


}

describe("Our data array", function() {
  it("has four items", function() {
    expect(players()).toBe(0);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The primary problem is that JSFiddle doesn't compile TypeScript to JavaScript for you.

Try the TypeScript playground and if you need to, copy the JavaScript across to JSFiddle.

## Additional Issues

You haven't enclosed the public method within a class... wrap your `players` method in a class... i.e.

```
class Example {
    public players(...) { }
}
```

You will need to create an instance of the `Example` class to use the method unless you make it static:

```
const example = new Example();
example.players(...);
```

You will also need to specify the property "selectedoptions" as you surprise the compiler when you suddenly reference it. Add this inside the class also:

```
private selectedoptions: any;
```

You also still have some work to do to make the method return a value. You aren't passing any arguments, so you have undefined-ness all over the shop.

If you get it "running", you'll see the test fails due to `options` being undefined:

http://jsfiddle.net/om4pc7s8/1/

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply...can you update in my fiddle its confusing :(

Comment: @texirv I have added a running JSFliddle link - it contains the compiled code obtained from http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html - it also has a link to jQuery, which you need. It runs, so you'll be able to then work on making the test pass.

Comment: any idea how to fix this error ?? TypeError: Cannot read property 'model' of undefined